# closing dropdown menus using angular js

Tags: angularjs, events

I am unable to understand how the element.find(event.target.)length>0 in the following code works

```
 $document.bind('click', function(event){
      var isClickedElementChildOfPopup = element
        .find(event.target)
        .length > 0;

      if (isClickedElementChildOfPopup)
        return;

      scope.isUserDropdownVisible = false;
      scope.$apply();
```

The example is from the following plunker link https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/fkAHzw

Answer (score 0):

The `element` is an HTML of your directive.

`$document.bind('click'` - the directive listens on any click in your document (view).

`event.target` - clicked HTML, button or link ...

So this snippet:

```
var isClickedElementChildOfPopup = element
    .find(event.target)
    .length > 0;
```

tells us that click is done inside your directive HTML and not out of it or parent component like a `<button>`

Comment: can you please explain how the .length property works here?

Comment: Find out how many elements there are in the document. Angular uses  jqLite. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element. `find()` - Limited to lookups by tag name. https://api.jquery.com/find/